# Trabajar vistas con datos personalizados de mis modelos y transferirlos a javascript - DJango

Tags: javascript, django

Estoy intentando desarrollar un proyecto en Django y no tengo claro cómo debería desarrollar la siguiente idea.

Tengo un modelo que contiene una serie de datos almacenados y me gustaría desde mis vistas:

1. Recopilarlos.
2. Generar nuevos datos a partir de los obtenidos.
3. Crear mi propia variable de tipo lista con los datos.

Esto lo quiero así porque estoy usando un framework que me pide los datos con una cierta estructura y prefiero trabajar en el *backend* y evitar hacer `scripts` en `JS`. (Y además porque quiero aprender a trabajar las vistas con más detalle).

Mi duda es, ¿debo emplear un `ListView` y modificar su `context_data` o debería crear una vista nueva? Más que nada porque no se hacer ninguna de las dos y querría enfocar mis esfuerzos en el camino "correcto".

De entrada he creado una función/vista propia pero no tengo claro que sea la mejor opción, además no se recogerle los datos correctamente desde `JS`.

Mi vista

```
def prueba(request):
    template_name ='pruebas/prueba.html'
    # Llamo al modelo con los datos
    data_model = workout.objects.all()
    # Aquí generaría los datos pertinentes
    # En este caso simulo la estructura ya final (simulo dos conjuntos de datos)
    dataset = [
        {
            'label': 'Prueba1',
            'values': [{'x':1, 'y':3}, {'x':2, 'y':8}],
            'migrate': 'true'
        },{
            'label': 'Prueba2',
            'values': [{'x':1, 'y':2}],
            'migrate': 'false',
        }
    ]

    return render(request, template_name, context={'Dataset':dataset})
```

Mis urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('prueba/', views.prueba, name='prueba'),
]
```

Ahora tocaría el `JS` pero no se obtener los datos de una vista.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('{% url "prueba" %}', function(dataset) { // Esto no se como hacerlo (ni siquiera si se hace así)
        console.log(data);
        // Si los datos llegasen bien debo convertirlos a JSON (ahora son string)
        var objw = JSON.parse(legumbre);
        console.log(objw);
    });
</script>
```

Mi pregunta sería, si esto es correcto, ¿cómo recojo los datos en `js`? Si no es correct, ¿Cómo debo afrontar el problema?

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la documentación de [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

Parámetros:

1. URL de la petición.
2. (Opcional) Datos que se agregarán a la URL, por ejemplo, `'variable=valor'` o `{variable: 'valor'}`; depende de lo que tengas en tu HTML, puedes enviar un formulario completo o solo lo que necesites.
3. (Opcional) Función a ejecutar cuando la petición termine normalmente; el parámetro que defines para esta función es para la respuesta que recibes.
4. (Opcional) Tipo de respuesta esperada.

Suponiendo que en el HTML tienes un `<select id="variable">` y es el que quieres incluir:

```
    $.get('{% url "prueba" %}', {variable: $('#variable').val()}, function(data) {
        // data ya debe ser un JSON si no hubo errores en la petición
        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
```

Si no deseas enviar datos, solo omite ese parámetro:

```
    $.get('{% url "prueba" %}', function(data) {
        // data ya debe ser un JSON si no hubo errores en la petición
        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: Primero de todo, MUCHAS GRACIAS. Y si no quisiera que fuese JSON? Por ejemplo pasarle una lista como la de mi ejemplo? Es que al final resulta que debo pasar una lista y dentro los diferentes JSON. Porque realmente tu solución es lo que ya había puesto forzando a JSON

Comment: La lista es un arreglo con objetos y, convertido a JSON, sigue siendo lo mismo. Hay que ver cómo la generas desde el servidor, pero debes recibir algo como `[{propiedad:valor}, {propiedad:valor}]` con tantos objetos como propiedades necesites.

Comment: Yo pensaba eso pero le hago un `dataset = json.dumps(dataset)` en la vista y luego aplico tu código y aunque no da error, el `console` no muestra nada, :/.

Comment: Desconozco _django_, pero se supone que deberías usar [JsonResponse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#serializing-non-dictionary-objects) para enviar el contenido. Otra referencia: https://zetcode.com/django/jsonresponse/